# Invoke Java object constant using a variable

Tags: java, reflection, invoke

I'm very new to Java so it makes it hard for me to explain what I'm trying to do.

I have an abstract class that invokes several object constants like this:

```
public abstract class Enchantment implements Keyed {
    /**
     * Provides protection against environmental damage
     */
    public static final Enchantment PROTECTION_ENVIRONMENTAL = new EnchantmentWrapper("protection");
```

In a different file I can access this perfectly fine with 
`Enchantment value = Enchantment.PROTECTION_ENVIRONMENTAL;`

However, I'm trying to use a string variable for this instead. Something like this:

```
String str = "PROTECTION_ENVIRONMENTAL";
Enchantment value = Enchantment.str;
```

Obviously that won't work. So I did a bunch of research and learned I need to use reflection for this. Using this source code's docs I figured I was looking for field data. So I tried both:

```
Field fld = Enchantment.class.getField("PROTECTION_ENVIRONMENTAL");
Field fld = Enchantment.class.getDeclaredField("PROTECTION_ENVIRONMENTAL");
```

But these returned me a NoSuchFieldException. As I was on it, I've tried both `getMethod()` and `getDeclaredMethod()` just as well equally with no luck.

I'm now at the point that these are probably "object constants"? I'm not sure how to call them. But I'm definitely at a loss on how to get this to work now and after everything I've tried myself, I figured it was time to ask for some help here.

Comment: *and learned I need to use reflection for this*. No. No no no. You shouldn't. Use a Map<String, Enchantment>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have the `Field`, you need to call [`Field.get(Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#get-java.lang.Object-) with an instance (in this case the `class`). Something like,

```
Class<?> cls = Enchantment.class;
try {
    Field f = cls.getField("PROTECTION_ENVIRONMENTAL");
    System.out.println(f.get(cls));
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Since you want the `Enchantment`, you ***could*** then test that the instance you get is assignable to `Enchantment`. Something like,

```
Class<? extends Enchantment> cls = Enchantment.class;
try {
    Field f = cls.getField("PROTECTION_ENVIRONMENTAL");
    Object obj = f.get(cls);
    if (cls.isAssignableFrom(obj.getClass())) {
        Enchantment e = cls.cast(obj);
        System.out.println(e);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But the `enum` approach is **better**.

Comment: This seems to be close, but how do I get `f.get(cls)` into `Enchantment value = `? When I tried it tells me it cant convert from Object to Enchantment. I'm probably really a beginner here, haha

Comment: @icecub See, that is the real issue here. If that Field is *really* an Enchantment, then you only need a **cast**. Seriously, honestly: a person who doesn't know why and how to *cast* objects java, such people lack the knowledge and experience to even get close to reflection. Reflection is something that even experienced java programmers avoid like the plague. It is never the first valid option, it is always the last resort when you lack any other solution!

Comment: @GhostCat Reflection is good to know (but I do agree the `enum` approach is better here).

Comment: Sorry I had to do some testing first, but your updated answer is working perfectly! Thanks for having some patience with me. You as well @GhostCat

Answer (score 3):

You may want to look into enumerations if you know they're going to be constant values;

```
public enum Enchantment {
    PROTECTION_ENVIRONMENTAL {
        public void cast() {
            // do enum-specific stuff here
        }
    },
    ANOTHER_ENCHANTMENT {
        public void cast() {
            // do enum-specific stuff here
        }
    },
    A_THIRD_ENCHANTMENT{
        public void cast() {
            // do enum-specific stuff here
        }
    };

    public abstract void cast();
}
```

enums can be treated like classes and have methods and properties.  You can also convert to and from strings `Enchantment.valueOf("PROTECTION_ENVIRONMENTAL")` but that's generally if you are reading from a configuration file - in code you'd reference the value directly.

Comment: This won't work because the abstract class also has methods and variables that aren't constant values. It seems that when I do this, those no longer work (they become undefined).

Comment: Java enums are pretty powerful, you can give them methods just like other classes - I've updated the answer with an example.

Comment: Thanks, I'll be sure to give this some more thought as well. For now the accepted answer works and as I've been on this all night (8 am in the morning for me now), I will get some sleep first, haha

Answer (score 3):

That one comment is spot on: you **absolutely** do not use reflection here.

There are only two valid reasons to use reflection:

- you are creating a framework that has to deal with classes it doesn't know about
- you have for some other reason to deal with classes you don't know about at compile time

But your code perfectly knows about that Enchantment class, its capabilities, and so on. Therefore *reflection* is the wrong approach. You figured it yourself: it is damn hard to get right, and damn right to get it wrong in some subtle ways. And when you get it wrong, it always blows up at runtime. Reflection code *compiling* means nothing. It always waits for you to run it to throw up in your face.

So to answer your question by not answering it: use a Map. Like:

```
Map<String, Enchantment> enchantmentsByConstantName = new HashMap<>();
enchantmentsByConstantName.put("PROTECTION_ENVIRONMENTAL", PROTECTION_ENVIRONMENTAL);
```

Alternatively, these constants could go into an enum, as outlined in the other answer, but in a sightly different way:

```
enum EnchantmentHolder {
  PROTECTION_ENVIRONMENTAL(new EnchantmentWrapper("protection")),
  ANOTHER_ENCHANTMENT(...)
  A_THIRD_ENCHANTMENT(...)
  ...;

  private Enchantment enchantment;

  private EnchantmentHolder(Enchantment enchantment) {
    this.entchantment = entchantment;
  }

  public Enchantment getEntchantment() { return entchantment; }
```

Comment: Yes, but the whole point of trying to use a variable is to "convert" the variable value into the class name. If I were to use a Map, I need to declare which string calls which class. I might as well just call it directly? Perhaps I'm overlooking something here, if so, my bad ^^

Comment: @icecub Nothing in your question said that you have fields of *different* types. And when everything is about Enchantments, that map or enum work! The point here is: java is a statically compiled language. You should design your application in ways that fit this paradigm, instead of trying to turn Java into some "somehow" dynamic language where you go forth and back from strings to code in such ways. Beyond that, this really screams XY problem. What is the *actual* problem you believe you can solve by having such constants, and where is the need coming from to call things "from strings"?

Comment: It's difficult to explain in short. I'm working on a plugin for a Minecraft Bukkit server. The server itself is in beta. So using the code provided to get all enchantments, it only returns half of them. The other half is implemented, just not in the "loop" to get returned yet. I can't modify the server source because the plugin wouldn't work for anyone else if I did. So I have to work my way around that and directly call the implementations from the plugin. I can do that manually, but with 500+ items, that would be insane. So instead I'm trying to convert the user command (string) directly